# War file deployment using maven and eclipse in JBOSS

Tags: maven, jboss7.x, pom.xml

I am trying to deploy war file in jboss-as-7.1.1.final. It is giving message BUILD SUCCESS but there is no war file in deployment folder. i searched on google and found many solution and tried almost all of them but it is not working.

my pom.xml is

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.test.demo</groupId>
  <artifactId>TEST</artifactId>
  <packaging>war</packaging>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <name>TEST Maven Webapp</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>3.8.1</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>

  <build>
    <finalName>TEST</finalName>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.2</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>${JAVA.VERSION}</source>
                <target>${JAVA.VERSION}</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <filteringDeploymentDescriptors>true</filteringDeploymentDescriptors>
                <warName>TEST.war</warName>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
                <groupId>org.jboss.as.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>jboss-as-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>7.1.1.Final</version>

                <configuration>
                    <force>true</force>
                    <jbossHome>F:\\TEST\\LUNA WITH  JBOSS7\\jboss-as-7.1.1.Final\\standalone\\deployments</jbossHome>       
                     <hostname>172.16.3.95</hostname>                   
                    <fileNames>
                        <fileName>target/TEST.war</fileName>
                    </fileNames>      

                </configuration>
            </plugin>

    </plugins>

  </build>

  <properties>
    <JAVA.VERSION>1.7</JAVA.VERSION>
    <NAME>TEST</NAME>
  </properties>
</project>
```

Please tell me what is wrong?

Comment: Did you try to execute maven with error/debug flags set (-e or -X)?

Comment: No, i didn't try. I am getting only build, clean, install and test option when right click on 'pom.xml' in eclipse

Comment: Right click again, choose for "Maven build..." there you can enter your steps (clean install for instance) *and* you can check a "debug output" option.

Comment: How are you trying to deploy it? FWIW the `org.jboss.as.plugins:jboss-as-maven-plugin` isn't configured right.